# Is there a difference between a gold fur and a white fur kitsune?

Tags: mythical-creatures, japanese, shinto

After a kitsune gains its ninth tail, its fur becomes either gold or white. Is there any specific reason why a kitsune would become white instead of gold and vise versa?

Comment: Colors definitely have symbolism.  Try googling symbolism of these colors in Japanese culture.